# Interrupting a transfer from Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, blobstore

I have rather large files to retrieve from blob storage and I'm thinking of resiliency.  If it fails to download, e.g. the network connection suffers a temporary interruption, it needs to retry x number of times.  However I'm noticing behaviour that I don't know how to deal with.

I'm replicating a network fault by simply unplugging my network cable in the middle of a transfer to my machine.  What then happens is that the transfer stops at x% and never moves on.  The session stays active, the transfer task is still open and the destination file remains locked.  Even after I plug the cable back in it just stays like this until I close down my PowerShell session (in this case ISE).

This is the command I'm using:

```
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -blob $file.Name -Container $containerName -Destination $localPath -Context $Context -clientTimeoutPerRequest 60  -ErrorAction Stop -Force
```

It never throws an error, it just gets stuck.  Is there anyway I can get this to timeout and return an error to throw to a catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It never throws an error, it just gets stuck. Is there anyway I can get this to timeout and return an error to throw to a catch block?

As you said, if network issue cause interruption during download blob via **Get-AzureStorageBlobContent** cmdlet, the error will not reach in catch block. If you’d like to restart the transfer and make the transfer start from the point of interruption, you could try to use [AZCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#other-azcopy-features). And AZCopy with in re-startable mode is supported for interruption caused by network or other issues during file transfer, which could help restart the transfer from the point of interruption.

Comment: Thanks.  A shame though.  I'm aware of AZCopy.  I was hoping to be able to do it with the cmdlet though.